# HTML Helper in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to use this overload of HTML.Textbox in MVC.

```
@Html.TextBox(string name, object value, string format, object htmlattributes)
```

The **name** represents the name of the texbox

The **Value** represents the value of the textbox i.e text inside textbox

The **htmlattributes** represents the HTML attributes

What does the **format** (the third parameter)  represents? How to use it? please provide an example.

Thanking you. Its a simple basic question. I have **searched** Google for this and did not get any answer.

Comment: your image is not clear!!

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs check this

Comment: have you seen it ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/649394/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-HTML-Helpers-Csharp

Comment: Yes, thanks. But that doesn't specify about this overload.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` represents the **name** of the texbox

The `Value`  represents the  **value** of the textbox i.e **text** inside textbox

The **htmlAttributes** you can specify your

```
 id for the control and css classes
```

**String Format** you can specify formats like this `"{0:d MMM yyyy}"`

**For example:**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor("txtDate","somedate","{0:d MMM yyyy}", new { @class="input-large" })
```

Comment: Is it specially used for date formats or any other formats? where I can get the documentation for all the other formats?

Comment: @I could not find any documentation for it. yes i think it is especially meant for date fields formatting.

Comment: It is NOT _"especially meant for date fields formatting"_ You can use it for numbers as well, for example - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.myDecimal, "{0:C"}")` to format as currency. [Formatting Types in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx)